# using domain name in localhost

Tags: apache, localhost

i have problem to using domain name in localhost
i'm using `windows 8.1 64 bit` and my xampp in `drive F`

i'm already edit `httpd.conf` in `F:\xampp\apache\conf` to load vhost

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

already edit too `httpd-vhosts.conf` in `F:\xampp\apache\conf\extra`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/itklan/public/"
   ServerName mydomain.dev
   ServerAlias mydomain.dev
     <Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/itklan/public/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

i'm adding to `host` in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

```
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       mydomain.com
```

already restart `apache`...and i even restart my windows

but i still get something like this in google chrome

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

hm where i'm missing?
*ps : i still can access `http://localhost:8080/itklan/public/` normaly*

---

**update**

when i try to ping `mydomain.dev` it's success receiving all data from my localhost ip like this

[image]

and i test to run 127.0.0.1 it's showing

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

of cource because i change my apache port to `8080` and mysql port to `4433`
so it's should 127.0.0.1:8080 to open xampp home page

based on [this](https://serverfault.com/a/246474/277709) page -> *thanks to abdula* 
i try to edit 'httpd-vhosts.conf' and make it listen port 8080
but when i add script `Listen 8080` my apache wont run again
i tried to change that script to `Listen 80` and it's make my apache can running again. i notice if apache open ports now become 3 `(80, 8080, 4433)`
so i guess i don't need to add `Listen 8080` again because my apache already listen to that port
so i just changed the rest like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/itklan/public/"
   ServerName mydomain.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

and in `hosts file`

```
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1  mydomain.dev
```

but it's still same

Comment: Are you accessing your website with `www` prefix?

Comment: @vitozev no..i access it just by `mydomain.com` in url bar

Comment: what if you try to ping mydomain.com?
what if you add to your hosts file the following? localhost mydomain.com I don't know why but it seems that for newer Windows localhost is not an exact alias of 127.0.0.1

Comment: what if you try to ping mydomain.com? 
what if you add to your hosts file the following?

`localhost mydomain.com`

I don't know why but it seems that for newer Windows localhost is not an exact alias of 127.0.0.1

Comment: @luca3003 please check my updated post

Comment: With your apache set on listen:80

did you check if you have the port 8080 used by other software?

`netstat -an`

if your 8080 port is free and available, try to check the firewall...

Comment: To force HTTP, one must use `http://` explicitly, else it will default to HTTPS and route via 443. In none of the definitions above, do I see a listener on port 443 hence the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Answer (score 0):

> > > Don't use **`.com`** domain. use **`.dev`** or something which not available

and try this host

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.dev>    
    DocumentRoot F:/xampp/htdocs/itklan/public/  
    ServerName mydomain.dev
    ServerAlias server  
</VirtualHost>
```

[VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

---

**EDIT 01**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot F:/xampp/htdocs/itklan/public/  
ServerName mydomain.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i still have a problem with domain `.dev` is that because i change my `apache port to 8080` and `mysql port to 4433`

Comment: i already try in that link...when i add `Listen 8080` in `httpd-vhosts.conf` my apache can't run again after restart, i tried to add `Listen 80` and it's no problem when i restart apache....i notice if apache open port become 3 after that....default without `Listern 80` -> open ports (8080, 4433)...but when i add `Listen 80` it's become 3 like this open ports (80, 8080, 4433)...so i guess it's no need to insert `Listen 8080' in `httpd-vhosts.conf` and the rest i already follow that link but no progress

Answer (score 0):

It might sound silly or unlikely, but you didn't seem to mention checking your Firewall settings.

Though you're conceptually connecting to yourself, port 80 and 443 can have different restrictions by default and you may want to try allowing inbound ports for TCP or UDP whichever is suitable for your needs.